# How to remove top level bullet/indent on resume template?

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize, templates, bullets

I am working on creating a resume using Latex using the popular resume template on Overleaf found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/resume-shubhi-rani-apr-2019/fhxzrkcmjzjp).

I like this template, however I would like to remove one of the levels of bullet points and indentation.

For example, here is a screenshot from the template online:

[image]

I would like to remove the first level of bullets so that the text for education, languages, and Experience are all flush with the left start (ie remove the bullets and indentation). I would just like to preserve the bullet points for the sub points to each experience (the hollow bullet points) while formatting the rest of the text normally.

What I tried: I tried simply deleing the `\resumeSubHeadingListStart` line for each section and then also adding `\item[]`. This kind of worked in some sections but not others, but created a problem where the indentation of the text is still there (just no bullet point) and then the text on the right (the location and date) are now shifted towards the left and no longer flush with the right most side.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here or how to fix this?

Similar output I would like is to remove these and push this text to the left without altering the right text alignment:

[image]

**Edit:** desired result for formatting:

[image]

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(updated)** Add just before  `\begin{document}`

```
\renewcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt, label={}]} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStartx}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]} %
    
\renewcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
    \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
        \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

The first command  will suppress the bullets in Education, Experience an Skills while keeping the hollow bullets. Together with the third suppress left an right indentation

[image: c]

The second command is to use the black bullet if so wanted. For example:

```
\section{Academic Projects}
\resumeSubHeadingListStartx % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< fulled bullets
\resumeSubItem{Plug board Proxy (Networking)}{Developed a plug board proxy that adds an extra layer of encryption to connections towards TCP services. Clients running on same server connect to pbproxy, which then relays all traffic to actual services. (Mar '16)}
\resumeSubItem{Asynchronous Work Queue Manager (Kernel Programming)}{Developed a kernel module to serve as an asynchronous work queue manager with configurable worker threads. Implemented netlink sockets to propagate callbacks from kernel to user land and throttling to improve job extraction latency. (Nov '15)}
```

[image: b]

Comment: I have accepted the answer - but one last quick question sorry (not to be pedantic) but is there also a way to accomplish this by preserving the indent of the hollow bullets? It is perfect now that all the text is right aligned but I had hoped to keep the bullets for experience still indented how they were before.

Comment: @Ethan Try  for example `\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStartx}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=20pt]} ` instead of `\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStartx}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}`